# Can an Asteriod be marshalled as a spacecraft providing sufficent earth like gravity for those on it

Tags: gravity

Can a sufficient massed and size asteroid in a safe area from earth have engines added and provide earthlike gravity for occupants to bring them reasonably close to planets and earth for supply and landers. If so what type of mass how could it be done.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration.  I'm not sure what one question you are asking. Without one distinct question you are likely to get more downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

For providing Earth-like gravity it would need to be of mass similar to Earth - and that makes it a planet, not an asteroid. Even Ceres, recently upgraded from asteroid to dwarf planet has gravity about $1 \over 36$th of Earth.

Comment: more accurately one-thirty-sixth of earth. http://timesless.com

Comment: and once [these guys](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41188/12102) are done with it, Ceres will have even lower gravity.